# HighCharts: Is it possible to remove every other value on the x-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As you can see the months on the x-axis on the following [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/dNeVF/1/) overlap. On my chart i use rotation to get round this problem but I'm wondering is it possible to miss out values?

For example:

The X-axis currently goes 'January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'

Is it possible to change this to: 'January', 'March', 'May', 'July', 'September',  'November' and so on.

The easiest way of course would be just to delete them as i did above; however i pull my X-axis from a database using:

```
xAxis: {
                    categories: [<%=GraphDate%>]
                    ,
                    labels:
                    {
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right',
                        style:
                        {

                        }
                    }
                },
```

Is there a method to miss out every other value on the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/dNeVF/2/

Check:

```
labels: {
  step: 2
}
```

More info in documentation: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--step